# Scala Generic Repository Class For Reactive Mongo Repository(alpakka) - Needed Class Found T

Tags: scala, generics, akka, alpakka

Im trying to create a Generic Class in Scala so I can create a repository for different collection without repeating myself.

The problem is that if I do it as a Generic Class(as in this example) I get a problem in this line:

```scala
val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[T]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
```

> Expected Class but Found [T]

But if I change T for any other class (lets say User) in all the code it works.

This is my class:

```scala
    package persistence.repository.impl
    import akka.stream.Materializer
    import akka.stream.alpakka.mongodb.scaladsl.{MongoSink, MongoSource}
    import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}
    import akka.{Done, NotUsed}
    import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients
    import constants.MongoConstants._
    import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.{fromProviders, fromRegistries}
    import org.mongodb.scala.MongoClient.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
    import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.Macros._
    import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters
    import persistence.entity.{ProductItem}
    import persistence.repository.Repository
     
    import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
    class UserMongoDatabase[T](implicit materializer: Materializer,
                            executionContext: ExecutionContext)
      extends Repository[T] {
      val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[T]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
      val client = MongoClients.create(HOST)
      val db = client.getDatabase(DATABASE)
      val requestedCollection = db
        .getCollection(USER_COLLECTION, classOf[T])
        .withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
      val source: Source[T, NotUsed] =
        MongoSource(requestedCollection.find(classOf[T]))
      val rows: Future[Seq[T]] = source.runWith(Sink.seq)
     
      override def getAll: Future[Seq[T]] = rows
     
      override def getById(id: AnyVal): Future[Option[T]] = rows.map {
        list =>
          list.filter {
            user => user.asInstanceOf[ {def _id: AnyVal}]._id == id
          }.headOption
      }
     
      override def getByEmail(email: String): Future[Option[T]] = rows.map {
        list =>
          list.filter {
            user => user.asInstanceOf[ {def email: AnyVal}].email == email
          }.headOption
      }
     
      override def save(obj: T): Future[T] = {
        val source = Source.single(obj)
        source.runWith(MongoSink.insertOne(requestedCollection)).map(_ => obj)
      }
     
      override def delete(id: AnyVal): Future[Done] = {
        val source = Source.single(id).map(i => Filters.eq("_id", id))
        source.runWith(MongoSink.deleteOne(requestedCollection))
      }
    }
```

This is my repository trait:

package persistence.repository

```
import akka.Done

import scala.concurrent.Future

    trait Repository[T]{
      def getAll: Future[Seq[T]]
      def getById(id: AnyVal): Future[Option[T]]
      def save(user: T): Future[T]
      def delete(id: AnyVal): Future[Done]
      def getByEmail(email:String): Future[Option[T]]
    }
```

Comment: You can't get a class of an arbitrary type `T` you may rather ask for an implicit `ClassTag` for `T` and use that to get its `runtimeClass`

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, this is the perfect example of usage of `ClassTag` in Scala. It allow to retain the actual class of a generic/parameterized class.

```scala
class DefaultMongoDatabase[T](implicit ..., ct: ClassTag[T])
  extends Repository[T] {
  val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(ev.runtimeClass), ...)
```

*(You can move the classtag logic in the trait if you want.)*